# How many websites can I host on wordpress business?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, wordpress-theming, web-development-server

my friend and I recently bought Wordpress business and we thought that we would be allowed access to create multiple websites with premium themes and other benefits however it seems as though we can only have access to the themes for one year which is very confusing. Is there a way in which we could make websites for clients on this one site plan and the move it to th client's host and start out site from scratch for the next client?

The Wordpress people are not available to schedule a meeting with us until the end of the year sadly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to purchase some hosting and setup subdomains for your client's with the free download you get from wordpress.org.

I use a resseller account for my clients and have zero problems!
Hope this helps